# How to remove the select all option from a v-data-table?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetify-datatable

I need to hide the select all option from a v-data-table, the vuetify component. According to the documentation including the header-prop, single-select as true should do it but is not working.

```
<v-data-table
v-model="selected
:headers="headers"
:items="items"
show-select
:header-props="{singleSelect:true}"
></v-data-table>
```

Comment: `single-select` prop leads to disabling the ability to select multiple rows. Do you really want to achieve this behaviour? If yes, you can just apply this prop to `v-data-table` component directly

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be able to only select **one item** at a time you can add `single-select` directly to `v-data-table`:

```html
<v-data-table
  v-model="selected"
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
  show-select
  single-select
></v-data-table>
```

If you want to be able to select **multiple items** you can override the select all checkbox with the `header.data-table-select` slot:

```html
<v-data-table
  v-model="selected"
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
  show-select
>
  <template #header.data-table-select></template>
</v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 3):

I use slot to overwrite the select-all.

```
<v-data-table
  v-model="selected"
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
  show-select
>
  <template v-slot:[`header.data-table-select`]></template>
</v-data-table>
```

and if you could put a title for sue, like this:

```
<v-data-table
  v-model="selected"
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
  show-select
>
  <template v-slot:[`header.data-table-select`]>Selected</template>
</v-data-table>
```